# Use Calendar table to generate historical view of the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a `created_date` (timestamp) on 1 of my tables, that also has the `duration` column of a project, and I need to join with another table that only has `first_day_of_month` column that has the first day of each month, and other relevant information.

**Table 1**

```
id    project_id    created_date    duration
1       12345        01/01/2015       10
2       12345        20/10/2015       11
3       12345        10/04/2016       13
4       12345        10/08/2016       15
```

**Table 2**

```
project_id    month_start_date
12345        01/01/2015       
12345        01/02/2015       
12345        01/03/2015       
12345        01/04/2015       
...
12345        01/08/2016
```

**Expected result**

```
project_id    month_start_date  duration
12345        01/01/2015          10
12345        01/02/2015          10
...
12345        01/10/2015          11
12345        01/11/2015          11
...
12345        01/04/2016          13 
12345        01/05/2016          13
12345        01/06/2016          13  
...
12345        01/08/2016          15
```

I want to be able to present the data listed in my second table historically. So, basically I want the query to return the same `duration` related to the `month_start_date`, so that values will repeat until another `dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,created_date),0) = first_day_of_month` is met... and so forth.

This is my query:

```
select table2.project_name,
       table2.month_start_date,
       table1.duration,
       table1.created_date
from table1 left outer join table2
   on table1.project_id=table2.project_id
where dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,table1.created_date),0)<=table2.month_start_date
group by table2.project_name,table2.month_start_date,table1.duration,table1.created_date
order by table2.month_start_date asc
```

but I get repeated records on this:

**Result I'm getting**

```
project_id    month_start_date  duration
12345        01/01/2015          10
12345        01/02/2015          10
...
12345        01/10/2015          10
12345        01/10/2015          11
...
12345        01/04/2016          10
12345        01/04/2016          11 
12345        01/04/2016          13 
...
12345        01/08/2016          10
12345        01/08/2016          11
12345        01/08/2016          13
12345        01/08/2016          15
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: I'll add that the schema of the tables you currently have will help.

Comment: i edited the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` operator.

Here is one possible variant. For each row in your calendar table `Table2` (for each month) the inner correlated subquery inside the `CROSS APPLY` finds one row from `Table1`. It will be the row with the same `project_id` and the first row with `created_date` before the `month_start_date` plus 1 month.

```
SELECT
    Table2.project_id
    ,Table2.month_start_date
    ,Durations.duration
FROM
    Table2
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) Table1.duration
        FROM Table1
        WHERE 
            Table1.project_id = Table2.project_id
            AND Table1.created_date < DATEADD(month, 1, Table2.month_start_date)
        ORDER BY Table1.created_date DESC
    ) AS Durations
;
```

Make sure that `Table1` has index on `(project_id, created_date) include (duration)`. Otherwise, performance would be poor.

Comment: i'm using sql 2012 and it does not seem to recognize the Lateral join, is this correct? what other workaround can i use?

Comment: @Synamoon, you tagged your question as Postgres, not SQL Server, so you've got an answer for Postgres. SQL Server's syntax for lateral join is `CROSS APPLY`.I'll retag the question for you and add an answer with SQL Server syntax.